# A 'deselect' keystroke?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, silverlight, keystrokes

There is probably not a way to do this, but here's the situation:

I am running a Silverlight 4 app in Google Chrome, and on occasion I hit cmd-A (select all) out of habit. It selects the entire SL frame, making it all blue, and I can't deselect it because there is no other element as far as the browser is concerned. Is there a way to deselect current item with a keystroke or something? I am using Google Chrome.

Thanks,
Alec

Comment: Does an arrow key work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter the following into the address box to deselect everything

`javascript:void(window.getSelection().removeAllRanges())`

To make it easier to use, you can make it a bookmark.

1. Control-click the bookmarks bar and choose Add page.
2. In the Name field, enter *Select None* or something like that.
3. In the URL field, copy and paste the javascript address above.

Now if you accidentally press command-a, you can click on the Select None bookmark.

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you hit ESC?

Comment: The SL frame is responding to most keystrokes, so nothing :(